# How to use nested field in Elasticsearch filter script

Tags: elasticsearch

I have following mappings:

```
 "properties": {
      "created": {
        "type": "date"
      },
      "id": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "identifier": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "values": {
          "properties": {
            "description_created-date": {
              "properties": {
                "<all_channels>": {
                  "properties": {
                    "<all_locales>": {
                      "type": "date"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "footwear_size-option": {
              "properties": {
                "<all_channels>": {
                  "properties": {
                    "<all_locales>": {
                      "type": "keyword"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

Now I would like to create a query based on description_created-date field and use this value in painless script by comparing to some date.

```
GET index/pim_catalog_product/_search
{
  "query": {
    "constant_score": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": [
            {
              "script": {
                "script": {
                  "source": "doc['values']['description_created-date']['<all_channels>']['<all_locales>'].value == '2019-12-19'",
                  "lang": "painless"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I get following error:

```
{
  "shard": 0,
  "index": "index",
  "node": "cmh1RMS1SHO92SA3jPAkJA",
  "reason": {
    "type": "script_exception",
    "reason": "runtime error",
    "script_stack": [
      "org.elasticsearch.search.lookup.LeafDocLookup.get(LeafDocLookup.java:81)",
      "org.elasticsearch.search.lookup.LeafDocLookup.get(LeafDocLookup.java:39)",
      "doc['values']['description_created-date']['<all_channels>']['<all_locales>'].value == '2019-12-19'",
      "    ^---- HERE"
    ],
    "script": "doc['values']['description_created-date']['<all_channels>']['<all_locales>'].value == '2019-12-19'",
    "lang": "painless",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
      "reason": "No field found for [values] in mapping with types [pim_catalog_product]"
    }
  }
}
```

(I know I can't compare dates like this, but this is another problem).

Searching by `values.description_created-date` field works:

```
GET index/pim_catalog_product/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "values.description_created-date.<all_channels>.<all_locales>": "2019-12-19"
    }
  }
}
```

And when I get specific document, value of this field is presented like this:

```
"values": {
  "description_created-date": {
    "<all_channels>": {
      "<all_locales>": "2019-12-19"
    }
  }
}
```

How can I use this field in script filter? I need this to perform something like this:

```
(pseudocode)
"source": "doc['values']['stocks_created-date'].value > doc['created'].value + 2 days"
```

I'm using elasicsearch v6.5.0, here is a docker-compose file with elasticsearch and kibana:

```
version: '3'
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.5.0
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.5.0
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
```

and gist with full mappings and sample data [here](https://gist.github.com/jan-kran/0cca0e779b4ee826cd7485008cb68eb7#file-create_index-json)

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that the property `values` is within your `pim_catalog_product` type? Also, in your provided abbreviated mapping, I didn't see the `stocks_created-date` property within your `values` mapping.

Comment: @JamesWoodruff sorry for misleading mappings. I've updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the expanded mappings! When calling a field within a nested object, try referring to the inner field using the dot notation. Example:

```
"source": "doc['values.description_created.<all_channels>.<all_locales>'].value == 2019"
```

Also, you could reduce your compound queries to just your main `constant_score` compound query. Example:

```
GET index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "constant_score": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": {
            "source": "doc['values.description_created.<all_channels>.<all_locales>'].value == 2019"
          }
        }  
      },
      "boost": 1
    }
  }
}
```

NOTE: The "boost" value is optional, but it's the default if you don't provide a boost value.